# Issue with IE recording in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I tried recording `.net application` with Jmeter. I kept getting 'Page can't be found' error during recording. I changed the IE proxy server setting and configured the port number.
Not sure why it's not able to capture anything within the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare JMeter for recording, the fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

     [image]
2. Prepare Internet Explorer for recording:

   - [Configure IE to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Internet-Explorer):

     [image]
   - [Install JMeter's MITM certificate into IE](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206082128-How-to-install-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Internet-Explorer-):

     [image]
3. If your machine uses corporate proxy for Internet access - [configure JMeter to use this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
4. That's it, you should be able to record now.

Comment: I tried multiple ports, it didn't work. Basically I am using the recording template, installed the JMeter cert and set the browser port as JMeter Port. I keep getting 'Page Can't be found' error. Any suggestions?